Permanent night on a portion of a planet
Some time ago I had a D&D setting where there was a portion of the world that was dominated, amongst other undead types, a vampire dynasty. The fact that this land existed under permanent night made their jobs a bit easier.
The environment I wanted to create was a land with permanent night and a constant moon visible. I was never able to rationalize, without magic handwavium, how this could be. Maybe somehow though orbital mechanics and tidal locking with the moon creating a permanent eclipse shadow. But could never reconcile how this would work.
I gave an answer to a question some months ago that was recently resurrected, on how to extend the length of seasons. I don't know why I didn't make the connection at that time but here I am.
So the question: In a solar system, more or less the same as our own, could we have a planet like earth in most all respects except that it has an accelerated axial precession that causes one of the poles to always face away from the sun, resulting in a permanent night at that pole?
Is this arrangement unstable in that it would be impossible to exist for more than than ten thousand(ish?) years.
Not to violate the one question rule. But the main question is achieving a permanent night at the pole, is the goal hopefully a tidal locked moon does not invalidate this possibility. That will spin up a separate question, I suppose. As well as questions about what climate eccentricities would evolve under these circumstances.
EDIT:
By some of the answers as good reading as they are, I may have been unclear. The aim is to create a planet that one pole always faces away from the sun. Earth does this every season but not permanently. In winter in the northern hemisphere the sun sets for six months at the extreme north.
The problem is that Earth's orbit, as it goes around the sun the pole begins to point toward the sun again, and we get 6 months of daylight at the extreme north in summer.

All this because the earth is at a tilt relative to the orbital plane. However the tilt, or the angle of the tilt, is not fixed. It rotates, like a wobbly top. But one "wobble" takes thousands of years.
I want to accelerate this wobble to one wobble in one year. I just don't know if a wobble/procession this rapid is possible and stable over many thousands of years.
On the planet anywhere except the poles, you would still experience day and night normally. No tidal locking to the star or anything else unusual. I only mentioned tidal locking as a possible characteristic for a moon in a futures question.
Despite having the sci-fi tag I hope to stretch reality as little as possible or optimally none at all, in the best scenario. Also, science based or hard science tags are often turned into the "Moon faced assassins of joy."

This seems ok to me - question is just “is a situation where 1 pole is always on the dark side unstable or stable over civilizational timescales?”.

We need an astronomer. What you want would be perfectly reasonable if it's possible for a planet to rotate on two axes. One the normal polar rotation that we experience on Earth. The other a perpendicular axis around which the planet rotate once each year (the definition of tidal locking). If a planet can rotate on two axes, this is stable. If it can't....

@JBH Note that this kind of precession is real, though. It's just a matter of lining it up right.

@controlgroup Cool! That answers the question. Even if real axial preceission can't rotate with a far enough axis to account for tidal locking, it' enough to rationalize the goal just fine. Do we happen to know of any planets tidal locked with ~20 deg tilt?

Not in our Solar System at least (although I'm sure there are exoplanets like that). We do, however, know that they can in theory become tidally locked, and that planets can have very high axial tilts (Uranus's is a whopping 97.7 degrees). I included both of those points in my answer, in fact :) Alternatively, if you're willing to suspend a disbelief and say the axial precession lines up with the orbital period to emulate tidal locking... you get pretty much the same thing, but for planets that are too far out to be locked.

I think planets can be tidally locked to stars directly.

Are you certain it's even desirable to have a planet and a solar system and orbits and so on in a setting like D&D with its distinctly non-physics-based cosmology, multiplicity of planes and demiplanes, sun and moon gods that you can physically interact with, and usually total lack of people who know how to do calculus? Your players can aspire to undo the ancient vendetta between Moon and Sun that has plunged the Feud-Lands into eternal darkness and allowed the vampires to reign supreme. Even if they could change orbits, they shouldn't want to, because they'd accidentally kill everyone.

"could we have a planet like earth in most all respects except that it has an accelerated axial precession that causes one of the poles to always face away from the sun" regardless of if this is possible, it's definitely plausible enough that I wouldn't bat an eye if I read it in a work of fiction, and one involving vampires no less.

Just a side note, if part of your planet has permanent night I would assume it to be mostly dead. There would be no plant life because no sun, no photosynthesis and in consequence no animal life. Humanoids could probably go exploring there but it would be a very inhospitable place to be.

@quarague you are correct, it would be very inhospitable, but not sterilized.

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18403/57209

@user721108 thanks for the link. I am getting mixed answers.  The link says it's absolutely not possible yet, we know it is because the earth behaves this way through axial precession.

a place with no direct sunlight is possible, there are valleys near the artic circle that never get direct sunlight.

I think it boils down to "I want to accelerate this wobble to one wobble in one year. I just don't know if a wobble/procession this rapid is possible and stable over many thousands of years.". This is a real physics question, how the wobble speed can relate to the rotation speed. You need to ask this at physics.stackexchange.com.

This wobble that you mention ("nutation" in the jargon) is tiny in the Earth's case -- just 17 seconds of arc. And this is to be expected, given the enormous angular momentum of a decent-sized planet. So I don't think you can use this mechanism to achieve your aims.

in addition to TonyK comment, and previous link, this one goes the same direction, regarding massive gyroscopes having somewhat small relative orbit around their star

The problem is that the energy involved in causing a planet-sized gyroscope to precess so rapidly would probably preclude the planet from having any kind of life at all. Or a solid surface, for that matter.

There is a situation in which part of a planet could have permanent night (and the opposite side have permanent day), but the "twilight zone" could still experience a day-night cycle of sorts, rather than the sun always being in the same near-horizon location in that habitable section.
You start with a tide-locked planet; better put it a little further out than you normally would (i.e. it should seem like it ought to be too cold).  This is because you're going to put it on a fairly eccentric orbit, perhaps close to the eccentricity of Mercury's orbit.  This will result in significant libration, whereby the rotation of the planet (very nearly constant angular rate) isn't exactly the same rate as the orbital revolution (same period, mind you).
The variation in orbital velocity means the sun will appear to move in the sky -- several degrees, maybe even tens of degrees if you're close to tipping over into a 3:2 rotation/orbit resonance like that of Mercury.  This would give fairly large areas near the sunward and night poles with permanent day or night -- but could leave as much as 50% of the surface with an "up and down" solar cycle, where the sun rises up the sky for a while, then comes to a near-stop before dropping back down to set in about the same place on the horizon where it rose.
Now, you needed the planet a little on the cold side because this eccentricity of orbit is exactly what pumps up Io's internal heat engine to make it the most volcanic body in the Solar System.  On a planetary scale, there likely wouldn't be quite this much tidal heating (there's no evidence Mercury is heated excessively by Solar tides) -- but it'll certainly create some geothermal heating, leading to a higher rate of vulcanism and hot spring activity than on Earth.

Will definitely keep his in my pocket but, from the perspective or the rest of the world I would like it to appear as "normal" as any other vampire infested fantasy world. To set up a "not in Kansas anymore" moment.

Those places do exist.

There is two ways one can get this situation: on moons (or smaller bodies) without atmosphere topography can be rought enough that the depths of bigger craters are never touched by the star's light. These places actually do exist on our Moon near the poles, as do places with eternal light. Having these in close proximity is a very desirable location for lunar bases as the eternal light guarantees eternal power generation while the eternal night down in the crater guarantees that your heat sinks will continue to work 24/7. 
This scenario requires small axial tilt (the smaller, the better the chances, and well possible) and smaller bodies as both, an atmosphere will scatter light, thus night will not be absolute, but just like shade or twilight here on Earth. The density of the atmosphere decides which happens. Additionally, large-scale topography is worn down by weather and gravity more easily and quicker the more massive the planet.

The other option is a tidally-locked planet around its central star. That way one side is always exposed to the sun, the other in eternal darkness. That definitely makes the planet a hell to live on, and there are many issues with keeping an atmosphere - but one might come up with some fringe conditions, like a dense atmosphere which distributes heat sufficiently enough (actually similar to Venus which has very long nights in the order of months (~117 days) as it is a very slow rotator) where a Venus day lasts longer than a Venus year.

There is a theoretical third option - but it mathematically has the probability of zero: a moon around a planet which rotates just so that one side always faces the star and the other doesn't. But deviate slightly from this, you are again at a situation described above, similar to Venus.



The third option is interesting, and I don't think the probability is zero.  Despite all the other tidal forces on the moon, it is affected by tides from the star to some degree and it would tend to be (slightly) stabilized at that position.  I don't expect to see it, but we're not talking about a rooster's egg on a ridgepole here - there is some finite chance.

@MikeSerfas anything which affects the moon gravitationally also induces tides. And tides mean that rotation rate changes. So it's a naturally unstable situation as #3 does not mean tidally-locked (as it would rather tidally lock to its parent planet which induces stronger tides). One can come up with some kind of mean motion resonances... not sure whether they can create (on average) this situation. I'm sceptical

the moon would "rather" lock to the planet, yes, but imagine it has a large mountain range and it is currently tidally locked to the sun.  If the moon started spinning just slightly fast so that the range was gradually moving to a high-potential-energy position relative to the sun, then it would be pulled backward.  But since the moon is still rotating steadily versus the planet, it would be pulled in every direction over time with little net effect.  Sometimes a thrown ball can come to rest on a high shelf if there's a little lip to catch on, and the same is true of planets.

I might not be accounting for everything, but my two cents: you could very well have a very large axial tilt and a precession that matches the orbital period. This doesn’t seem like it’d be unstable; consider Mercury, which is in 3:2 orbital resonance with the Sun but is not locked to it. See also Uranus which has a very, very, very inclined axis.
You specifically do not want tidal locking - this would make one side always day and one side always night, which doesn’t correlate to the planet’s poles. I bring up Mercury, though, because it shows that you can have tidal effects that for planets orbiting suns are not sufficient to lock it or what have ye over such timescales (locking doesn’t really occur on sub-100,000y timescales anyway).
So I would imagine a planet that, while forming, happened to have an axial precession period that almost-exactly matched its orbital period. I use Mercury (which is not locked tidally or by precession despite its very close proximity to the Sun) as the argument for realism here.
The moon, perhaps, is not a “moon”, but is a gas giant. The planet we’re talking about is following it around at a Lagrange point, making it always faintly visible over the horizon. Handwave the gas giant as exceptionally large in radius and the orbit exceptionally tight so you can make it out with naked eyes; that’s as good as you’re going to get, though, since the Lagrange points near the planet where a moon’s surface would be clearly visible is not stable and the moon would crash into the planet or spin off to another L-point quickly. Alternatively, if you really want a moon, handwave a highly-inclined orbit of a regular moon so it circles around the horizon as seen from the poles. It might not be visible at all times depending on topography, but it’d be visible more often than our moon is. When I have access to a digital notepad I’ll draw up some sketches of diagrams to make what I’m saying a bit clearer.

Note that I said “almost-exactly” instead of “exactly.” In nature, nothing happens exactly. But I also wanted to suggest the idea that, at the pole where all the vampire cities are, there are rumors that the vamp-geometers have been noticing a slight apparent axial precession, and that one day, it will become day on the poles, and the vampires will all be disintegrated as their cities pass under the terminator. Just a thought.

(Daylight is coming, No spoilers!) Nice answer thank you!

"You could very well have [...] a precession that matches the orbital period": please show your work how such a system would be mechanically possible. Remember that planets are large objects and therefore almost spherical.

Nice idea, not sure of possible or not possible, but it's for a DnD world ([science-fiction] tag present), so seems in-universe fine by me.

Orbital mobile
Like a parent hanging decorative rocket ships over a crib, a prior society aborted a runaway greenhouse effect with a space sunshade.  Current proposals on Earth tend to be aesthetically reminiscent of Highlander II -- but the people on this planet did better, opting to create a single planetary sacrifice zone which would do without the Sun entirely, so that the rest might live.  They constructed a ring of weights and graphene cables just past L1 (the Lagrange point where an object can orbit in synchrony with the planet) that was too small to see from the surface, with an opaque sunshade suspended by several cables to a position fairly near Earth.  The cables were further designed to "orbit" (in a loose sense) so that the sunshade would cover the same area at most times of the day.  Very little thrust should be needed to keep the network in place as designed, and it can be provided by a very subtle tilt of the sunshade and some solar sails hidden from view a moderate distance behind it to provide any needed torque; the system is automated and should last a very long time.  (Note this infrastructure also serves as a space transit system, extending the reach of the planet's space elevator network)  The area shaded was mountainous with many north-south running deep valleys that are dark at dusk and dawn, completing the nurturing environment meant to recreate one of scenic glaciers people have seen in the archived videos from the end of the Ice Age.
The glaciers may not have taken root, but it was practically inevitable after so many centuries of interchangeable vampire movies that a team of crack biowarriors would witch up a pretty impressive implementation of the idea to guard their ecological experiment from interlopers.

Sun Too Big

The problem with the scenario --- permanent night at the pole --- is that stars these days are just too dog gone big. What gives? The Sun is about 100 Earth diameters across. This means that light from all over the Sun's disk will strike the Earth at all angles, and at all locations. That's a lot of light, and not enough night!


As you can plainly see, overinflated stars send light out in all directions, and owing to their gordosity, there is no place on a normal sized planet that won't get light from a very large fraction of the star's surface. So, what can we do about this?

Well, an alternative solution to messing about with precession is easy! You'll need a star that is nice and tiny! Say, 50 to 75 percent of the planet's diameter. This solution allows for most of the planet to have ordinary schedules of day and night, but would allow for certain areas to be bathed in twilight, whilst at the very top & bottom, perpetual night would reign.


Keep in mind: the more axial tilt your planet has, the less effective this solution will be, for the simple fact that the pole will rotate around the area of night ensuring that your vampires will get unwanted sunlight. Therefore, the planet should have as close to 0 degree tilt as possible.

2 questions. How can a star possibly be only 50% a planets diameter?  Second, on earth, "night" at the poles lasts 6 months. So it'sclearlypossible at least for a short time. Which is what I am investigating here, by accelerating the polar procession to 1:1 ratio 1 orbit to 1 procession of the planet.ie: perinatal night/winter.

@Gillgamesh --- You're the worldbuilder, so you just make the star smaller! As for the long nights (and opposing days) at the poles on Earth, this happens because of axial tilt. If you want to do polar precession, then why are you asking the question? The answer then becomes, you do polar precession such that one pole always faces away from the Sun. Problem solved!

About the only way I see this working is if it's a rogue planet that's escaped it's star and is flying through interstellar space, the sun is not a sun, it's a moon orbiting this rogue planet that someone somehow 'ignited'.. the question then is does such a small body of the dimensions you suggest have the mass to sustain the sort of reactions needed to burn like a sun, and if so what sort of lifespan are we looking at.

"About the only way I see this working.." Because unless your using some exotic super dense matter to make it work a 'bigger' body isn't going to be orbiting a smaller body which means your sun will have too be the one doing the orbiting and thus by definition your 'sun' is then a moon
